# How to select rows from two matrices to have one larger?

Tags: algorithms

You are given two matrices $$\mathbf{A}=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & \ldots & a_{1n}\\\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\a_{m1} & \ldots & a_{mn}\\\end{pmatrix},$$ and $$\mathbf{B}=\begin{pmatrix}b_{11} & \ldots & b_{1n}\\\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\b_{m1} & \ldots & b_{mn}\\\end{pmatrix},$$ of positive numbers.

We want to find, for $1\leq j\leq n$, a subset ${S}_j\subset\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ of at most two rows such that ${S}_i\cap{S}_j=\emptyset$ (for $i\ne j$) and $\left|\bigcup_{j=1}^n{S}_j\right|$ is as large as possible and for $i,i'\in{S}_j$, we have: $$a_{ij}\geq b_{i'j}.$$

I started by reducing the problem to a maximum matching problem. If we create $m$ nodes. For each column $1\leq j\leq n$, we create an edge between node $1\leq i\leq m$ and node $1\leq i'\leq m$ ($i\ne i'$) if there is no edge already and if $a_{ij}\geq b_{i'j}$. Next, run a matching algorithm on the created graph to find a maximum-cardinality matching ${M}$.

Do you have any hints on how to solve the problem? Am I on the right direction?